# How can I connect to VNC server using Delphi and Indy?

Tags: delphi, indy10, vnc-viewer

I have been trying the initialize a connection to VNC Server 7.0.1 using the following code in Delphi and Indy 10:

```
IdTCPClient.Host := myIP;
IdTCPClient.Port := 5900;
IdTCPClient.Connect;
```

On `Connect()`, I get an error:

> EIdSocketError with message 'Socket Error # 10061 Coonection refused.'.

I am trying to a create a VNC Viewer application in Delphi.

Comment: The error usually means that either 1) the IP you are connecting to is reachable, but the Port does not have a server listening on it, 2) the Port is listening, but its backlog of pending connections is full, or 3) the connection is being blocked, ie by a firewall. Unfortunately, there is no way for your client to know which condition is the culprit. All it can do is try to connect again, preferably with a delay in between each attempt.

Comment: I did try turning off my firewall temporarily. I also tried port 53959 on which the netstat showed that the vncserver.exe showed 'Established' state. But same error.

Comment: 53959 is not a port that VNC listens on. You did not show the netstat output, but I suspect that 53959 is actually the port which the established client connected from. Does netstat show VNC listening on port 5900? What is `myIP` set to, exactly?

Comment: Nestat is not showing any of the ports from 5900 in the output list.

Comment: Well, then that is why you can't connect to it. Your VNC is either not running, or is misconfigured. You need to fix that either way.

Comment: I'm guessing the reason why I can't see the listening port of Real VNC in Netstat is because I'm using the 'lite subscription'. So now I downloaded UltraVNC server and now I'm able to see two local ports (5800 & 5900) in listen state. But when I try to connect to any of these ports, from another machine I get connection timed out error. I used the public IP of the machine I'm trying to connect to.

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue (ie, did you configure port forwarding? Configure firewalls? ) rather than a  coding issue. Try asking about that on [sf].